# Constant-information scale transformation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, poisson-regression, scales, checking

I was recently introduced to the concept of **constant information scale transformations** in the book **Generalized Linear Model with Examples in R**, by Dunn and Smyth.

[image: im1]

With that, they mention in the book that:

> If many explanatory variables are included on the incorrect scale...

I've been searching in the web to clarify this concept but I haven't find good info. What is it that "correct scale" and how do we apply it when doing stats?

Is this scale a kind of transformation for the covariates or for the response? Can you help me out with a way to grasp this concept better? Please :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The constant-information scale transformation corresponds to a variance stabilizing transformation as discussed in chapter 5. In sec 8.7.3, it's relevant for helping choose a scaling for fitted values in a plot of residuals (one of the kinds discussed there) vs a transformed fitted value $h(\hat{\mu})$.

   (It's usually obvious enough when you need something like this)
2. Separately from that is the issue of whether the predictors ($x$'s) are correctly "scaled" to have a linear relationship with $\eta=g(\mu)$.

   For that task, partial residuals ($u_j$) are plotted against the corresponding predictor ($x_j$).